# Sed replace not functioning as expected

Tags: bash, sed, replace

I want to replace `listen = 127.0.0.1:9000` by `listen = '/var/run/php56-fpm.sock'`

`sudo sed -i 's/listen = 127.0.0.1:9000/listen = \'/var/run/php56-fpm.sock\'/g' /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf`

Error:

```
bash: -c: line 63: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
bash: -c: line 64: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, `A single quote may not occur between single quotes, even when preceded by a backslash.`, ref [Bash Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Single-Quotes.html#Single-Quotes)

Second, you may want to use some other char as separator instead of `/` as you have `/` in the replacement string.

So as a result:

```
sudo sed "s#listen = 127.0.0.1:9000#listen = '/var/run/php56-fpm.sock'#g" /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
```

don't use `-i` yet, have a look at the print out to verify if it works as expected.

Comment: Indeed, a lot of people forget about being able to use a different separator character such as ':', which also holds true when doing search and replace in vim.

Answer (score 2):

try using other chars rather than / for separation maybe?

```
sudo sed -i "s@listen = 127.0.0.1:9000@listen = '/var/run/php56-fpm.sock'@g" /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
```

OR

```
sudo sed -i "s/listen = 127.0.0.1:9000/listen = '\/var\/run\/php56-fpm.sock'/g" /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
```

The problem is that you are not escaping the `/` as `\/` but using @ as separator will fix your problem. You can use ANY separator in sed as soon as your are consistent.

And true from @David, use double quotes as per bash manual.

*tip: all UX files need EOF in the last empty line*

Comment: both are not working.

Comment: sorry, I corrected, from single to double quote enclosing, David is right :)